# AngularJS save() returns incorrect response from Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an angularJS site using a Web API backend.  I am trying to do a save and I am expecting to get back a resulttype enum which is defined below

```
public enum ResultType
{
    Success,
    InvalidAccountNumber,
    InvalidAddress,
    NotFound,
    Incomplete,
    Error,
    Unauthorized
}
```

Here is the code I used to set up my resource.

```
app.factory('NotificationOptInApi', function ($resource) {
return $resource(API_SOURCE + 'NotificationOptIn', {}, {
    'save': { method: 'POST', isArray: true }
});
```

});

Here is my call to save

```
$scope.saveNotifications = function () {
    var result = NotificationOptInApi.save($scope.notifications, function () {
        // check for failure
        if (result !== 'Success') {
            $scope.saveError = result;
            return;
        }
    });
};
```

Here is what I get returned

```
{0: "S", 1: "u", 2: "c", 3: "c", 4: "e", 5: "s", 6: "s", $get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function}
```

Here is the code that returns it.  Thsi is while I tried to return a list instead of a reusltType

```
public List<ResultType> Post([FromBody]dynamic notificationSubscriptionHolder)
    {
        List<NotificationSubscriptionData> notificationSubscriptions = notificationSubscriptionHolder.ToObject<List<NotificationSubscriptionData>>();

        Logger.Info("Update Account Notifications", string.Format("<updateAccountNotificationsToUser><NotificationSubscriptionData>{0}</NotificationSubscriptionData><user>{1}</user></updateAccountNotificationsToUser>", notificationSubscriptions, this.CurrentIdentity.Name));
        try
        {
            return _accountManager.UpdateAccountNotifications(this.CurrentIdentity.Name, notificationSubscriptions);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<ResultType>() { ResultType.Error };
        }
    }
```

This has worked in other places with no issue.  I can check the result and it will be 'Success'.  The difference I see here is I am saving an array so I had to set IsArray to true.  I currently have 1 item in the array I am saving. The response I get is an array of characters.  Put together they spell out "Success".

Is there a way for me to not get my response back as an array even though I am saving an array?  I also tried returning a List thinking I needed to return an array.  When I do this I get an array with 1 item in it but within that 1 item I have an array of characters that spells out Success.

Comment: could you show your angular code

Comment: very strange the IsArray in the angular documentation is supposed to say whether the returned object is an array and I am only returning a ResultType but if I have IsArrya set to false i get a push error.  If I set it to true I can successfully save but get the Array back.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source code i have come to some conclusion :

When is array is true ngResource module iterates over each item received in the response and it creates a new instance of a Resource.For this they are using angular.copy between response and the resource object . Since angular.copy works correctly only on arrays and object types but you are sending ["success"] which is a string so it does not work properly displaying character of arrays . Try below code in your editor and you will get the answer .To resolve this issues you should return a object like [{Message:"Success"}]

var obj = angular.copy('success', {});
  alert(obj);